# How to verify that the link was clicked using onbeforeunload function in javascript

Tags: javascript, integration-testing

I am trying to write an integration test using onbeforeunload function, where I click on the image and it launches the url page on the next tab. I need to verify that after the click, new tab was launched. With the script below, it returns false.

```
if (somename === 'complete') {
          var content = document.getElementsByTagName("someframe")[0].contentWindow;

          var unloadFlag = false;

          window.onbeforeunload = function (e){
            unloadFlag = true;
        }
        var imageClick = content.document.getElementById("imageLayer")
          imageClick.click();

        assert(unloadFlag === true, "unloadFlag is false");
}
```

Comment: You need to put the assertion in the callback for window.onbeforeunload.

Comment: Awesome! That was it - Thank you @Brian!